# How does Java compiler convert Collections that contain custom classes?

Tags: java, collections, arraylist, compilation, jvm

When the following code is written:

```
 List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
 list.add(i);
```

Java compiler doesn't issue a compile error, even though we are adding an int inside the arrayList, as it converts (by using the Wrapper Class Integer) it to the following code:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
list.add(Integer.valueOf(i));
```

However, what happens when I have a custom Class and I want to store objects in the collection? More specifically, what casting operations happen and can these operations be considered as additional overhead.

So is the following code:

```
Animal animal= new Animal();
ArrayList<Animal> list = new ArrayList<Animal>();
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++){
    animal.code=i;
    list.add(animal);
    animal= new Animal();
}
Animal temp;
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++){
temp=list.get(i);
}
```

converted by JVM to something like this:

```
Animal animal= new Animal();
ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++){
    animal.id=i;
    list.add((Object)animal);
    animal= new Animal();
}
Animal temp;
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++){
temp=(Animal)list.get(i);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Good first question.  To read up more on generics, type erasure and such, check out: [Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This phenomenon is called [*type erasure*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html).  You are close but not quite there.

It's as if the type parameters were removed from method calls and implicit casts were added to returns from methods.

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();  // The JVM sees only the raw type
```

Later in the `for` loop:

```
list.add(animal);  // No (Object) cast necessary, Animal is already implicitly an Object.
```

And in the second `for` loop:

```
temp = (Animal) list.get(i);  // Correct, a cast is inserted here.
```

This will happen with custom classes such as your `Animal` as well as any other type, such as `Integer` (as you've already pointed out, the `int` will get boxed as an `Integer`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was wondering if when using list.add(animal), the boxing is considered as overhead. More specifically, if the initial list of java collections was containing Animal objects instead of Object objects, would it be any performance difference, as I guess boxing wouldn't be neccessary?

Comment: There is no boxing with `list.add(animal)`.  [Boxing refers specifically to placing a primitive value in a wrapper object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7), and it is not a cast: `int` to `Integer`, `double` to `Double`, etc.  There is no overhead with `list.add(animal)`, because the JVM already sees `animal` as an `Object`; there is no cast here.

Comment: Ok, thanks very much again. I wasn't sure about it, now it's clear to my mind.